# Duplicate id issue , cannot reuse an id

Tags: html

I'm working on the following script :

`http://www.andwecode.com/playground-demo/pop-up-login-signup-box-jquery/pop-up-demo.zip`

it's a script that gives you a popup login form.

i would like that gmail and fb boxes (and any box i would add) to do the same action when I click on that login button in the bottom (action = the login form appears ).

I tried this in Gmail box :

`<a href="#1" class="social_box google" id="login_form" >
<span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>`

Basically, I added the ID : `(id="login_form")` and it worked fine !

The problem is that you can use the ID just once.

for example when i used it on Gmail box the login button became useless ..

any idea how to make all the boxes do the same action (go to the login form) ?

Comment: Use a class selector instead? Add class `login_form` and change where applicable `#login_form` to `.login_form`

Comment: just try change `id="login_form"` to `class="login_form"`

Comment: i searched in the source code to do so , but i can't find it :/ 

it started with this : 



`<div class="user_login">
<form>
<label>Email </label>
<input type="text" STYLE="background-color: ...`
there is no such thing like `login_form`

Comment: change the ID login_form that you added to class selector login_form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use a class and have jQuery (if you're fine with using it, which I see you are) do something like this:

```
$('.selector').click(function() {
    //code
    alert('clicked!'); //just to test...
});
```

If I'm reading your question correctly, it should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the functionality works only for one scenario is that **'`ID's` have to be unique'**, if you have duplicate ID's it will recognize only the id for the first element and it will ignore the rest.

You can achieve your result in two ways

1) **have same class** for all the boxes fb box,google box etc.
Example: **box-form** class for all the boxes

**HTML:**

```
<a href="#1" class="social_box google box-form"  >
<span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>
<a href="#1" class="social_box fb box-form"  >
<span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('.box-form').click(function() {
    //code

});
```

2) Apply different id for each box and combine the id's in jquery

**HTML**:

```
<a href="#1" class="social_box google" id="login-form" >
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>
    <a href="#1" class="social_box fb"  id="fb-form">
    <span class="icon"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></span>
```

**Jquery:**

```
$('#login-form, #fb-form').click(function() {
        //code

    });
```